# Spring Boot multiple ActiveMQ Artemis broker configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I need to connect my Spring Boot 3.1.2 application to multiple different ActiveMQ Artemis brokers.

If I try to connect only one in `application.yaml` it works well. But when I want to create two different JmsTemplates I cannot send message to broker with "Channel disconnected" error.

```
Failure captured on connectionID=076130d3, performing failover or reconnection now
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219006: Channel disconnected
```

It can connect to browser because I see it in the ActiveMQ Artemis console as a session.

My configuration is like this:

```java
    @Bean(name = "firstConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory firstConnectionFactory() {
        try {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616");
            cf.setUser("user");
            cf.setPassword("password");
            cf.setThreadPoolMaxSize(2);
            return cf;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Bean(name = "firstTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate firstTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template=new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(firstConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

and I try to use it in a service like this:

```java
    private final JmsTemplate firstTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public TestSender(@Qualifier("firstTemplate") JmsTemplate firstTemplate) {
       this.firstTemplate=firstTemplate;
    }

    ...
    
    private void createTestRecord() throws Exception {
        JmsEntity e = JmsEntity.builder()
                ...
                .build();
        String json = this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(e);
        LOGGER.debug(String.format("send message: %s", json));
        this.firstTemplate.convertAndSend("topic", json);
    }
```

If I try to configure it by `application.yaml` like this:

```
spring:
  artemis:
    mode: native
    user: user
    password: password
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
```

I can inject a JmsTemplate and it works well.

How can I configure a ConnectionFactory?